# How HTML file upload works?

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

HTML uses *form* to send data to web server. The data can be included in the url parameters or embedded in HTML Request body. But for a file, I don't know how it works. I want to know this because I see some difference between uploading file on web and desktop applications.

The desktop application usually provides a text box to allow the user input the locale path of the file. But for web applications, the text box is usually read only.It displays the file path when the file gets selected with the *browse* button. Is that just a design issue between desktop and web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is a bit unclear, but one important aspect about web applications (or HTML forms) is that they are sandboxed and cannot access local files directly. So the file upload picker does not allow direct input of the file name (which might be scripted), but only selection through an OS (or browser) supplied file choose UI (that the app or page cannot mess with).

Once the user has selected the file the page can access it, but it cannot make the selection itself (or surreptitiously).

A recent trend is to lock down desktop apps in the same manner. See for example Apple's sandboxing restrictions, that also do not allow apps to open random files without user intervention.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo. It sounds reasonable to me.JavaScript can't access local files, before HTML5, but the input file name is just a `String`. Why can't it be manipulated by JavaScript? I'm also confused by "Once the user has selected the file the page can access it". What does it mean? Does the page can manipulate the file after the selection?

Comment: JavaScript *can* access local files (at least since HTML5), but only files explicitly selected by the user. What I wanted to say is that there is no way for the app to directly access any file on the disk that it wants (whereas with other form fields it can override the user's input any way it wants before sending it to the server).

Answer (score 0):

> Is that just a design issue between desktop and web?

The implementation of a file upload form, whether desktop or web, is largely unimportant to the end result. Both desktop and web controls can utilize either a path string or a full-blown file navigator, though a desktop app is more likely to vary in its implementation. The only other difference is the destination: desktop apps tend to parse the file in memory and render it somehow, while web apps almost invariably upload it to a server (though this is subject to change: see the [HTML5 file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)), which then further operates on it.

Comment: I don't think a web app can utilize an arbitrary path string. All file selections must be "vetted" by the user.

Comment: @Thilo Lynx lets me do it just fine.

Comment: Lynx lets *you* input a file path. It won't let Javascript on the page (if it supports that at all), change that path or supply its own.

Comment: @Thilo My argument is that the control itself can utilize a path string, not the web app.

Comment: Okay. That is indeed a minor presentation detail. The question is a bit vague, so I am not sure what OP is really asking.

Comment: @Thilo Neither am I, but I'm fairly certain the answer is either yes or no (and given what I can understand, I lean toward yes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to clarify my question a little bit.Does web applications allow to input the path of local files to upload a file, like desktop applications?

Comment: Yes, they allow that. With Lynx, you can apparently directly type it. With most others, you use a selector window. But the point is that the user has to choose the file, not the program.